# WinSock2 - функция accept()

Tags: c++, winsock

> Функция разрешения входящего соединения через сокет формирует дескриптор нового сокета, возвращая значение типа SOCKET.

В [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winsock/complete-server-code) Microsoft приведён следующий пример использования функции:

```
// Изначальное объявление и определение сокетов
SOCKET ListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;  
SOCKET ClientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

// Некоторый код... 
// ListenSocket в состоянии прослушивания( listen() )  
ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);  

// Далее  
closesocket(ListenSocket);
```

Вопрос: будет ли корректно написать (можно ли вообще)

```
ListenSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);
```

для избавления от дополнительного сокета, так как (в примере от Microsoft) после вызова данной функции сокет прослушивания закрывается?

Comment: А как вы закроете сокет прослушивания, если значение перетрёте?

Comment: Он закрывается в случае если результат присваивается ClientSocket'у

Comment: Кем? Откуда `accept` может знать, в какую переменную присваивается результат?

Comment: Это явно определённо в примерах, строчка с закрытием сокета относится к `ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);` Второй случай - мой вопрос.

Comment: Вот эта фраза **"так как после вызова данной функции сокет прослушивания закрывается"** откуда появилась? Если это ваше пожелание, то как вы закроете сокет, если перетрёте значение `ListenSocket` результатом возврата из `accept`?

Comment: Исправил вопрос, действительно не ясно

Comment: Добавьте ссылку на пример заодно, так как всё равно ещё как-то мутновато.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> будет ли корректно написать (можно ли вообще)
>
> ```
> ListenSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);
> ```

Так писать можно (с точки зрения языка), но ошибочно с точки зрения утекания ресурсов. После подобной записи значение `ListenSocket` затирается и уже не получится закрыть прослушиваемый сокет, если конечно заранее не сохранить это значение куда-то ещё, например:

```
auto oldListenSocket = ListenSocket;
ListenSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);
// ...
close(oldListenSocket);
```

Но приведёт это всё к тому же, с чего и начинали, только с более мутными названиями переменных.

В общем случае, не стоит переиспользовать одну и ту же переменную для разных целей, даже если она уже не используется и не нужна. А в упомянутом случае помимо того, что она всё ещё нужна (чтобы закрыть сокет), использование той же самой переменной ломает самодокументирование программы, т.к. `ListenSocket` уже не является прослушиваемым сокетом, как это должно следовать из названия.